# MySQL Querying Unix Timestamps

Tags: mysql

I have a table that stores the date/time as a Unix timestamp.
Is it possible to query the table and pick out all the entries that are a Monday without having to query all the rows and process them outside of MySQL?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes is the answer you are looking for. RTM for the functions [DAYOFWEEK()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek) and also [FROM_UNIXTIME()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

Comment: Perfect! Thanks. add as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM your_table WHERE DAYOFWEEK(FROM_UNIXTIME(your_unix_timestamp_column)) = 2
```